# How do I correct the formatting of my .tex file?

Tags: latex

Please tweak the following Latex code to produce the exact table attached as an image below. My current code is almost perfect, except the panel name rows are too far left and all column names have 33cm written next to them. Thank you.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

{\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}      \begin{tabular}{l*{7}{>{\centering \arraybackslash}m{3cm}}@{}} \toprule       \addlinespace[3mm]        & \multirow{3}{3cm}{Migration} & \multirow{3}{3cm}{No. of migrants} & \multirow{3}{3cm}{Duration} & \multirow{3}{3cm}{Migrates to Kolkata} & \multirow{3}{3cm}{Migrates to urban area} & \multirow{3}{3cm}{Earnings of migrant worker, typical month} & \multirow{3}{3cm}{Working in business} \\       \addlinespace[12mm]    
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}\\
\hline \\       & \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textit{A: Endline 1 (18 months)}} \\       \addlinespace[1mm] \\
Treatment           &      -0.015&       0.002&      11.767&      -0.004&       0.002&      26.326&       0.042\\
                    &     (0.034)&     (0.041)&     (6.798)&     (0.066)&     (0.055)&    (19.011)&     (0.046)\\
[1em]
Control Mean        &        0.35&        0.39&       37.08&        0.36&        0.83&      139.89&        0.10\\
Observations        &         814&         814&         285&         285&         285&         285&         285\\
\addlinespace[1mm] \\           & \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textit{B: Endline 2 (3 years)}} \\
[1em]
Treatment           &       0.029&       0.032&      14.776&      -0.095&      -0.039&      30.574&       0.032\\
                    &     (0.032)&     (0.041)&    (15.332)&     (0.069)&     (0.059)&    (29.920)&     (0.042)\\
[1em]
Control Mean        &        0.29&        0.33&      125.09&        0.38&        0.83&      231.18&        0.15\\
Observations        &         840&         840&         256&         256&         256&         256&         256\\
\addlinespace[1mm] \\           & \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textit{C: Endline 3 (7 years)}} \\
[1em]
Treatment           &       0.045&       0.045&     -11.078&       0.067&       0.012&      89.788&       0.017\\
                    &     (0.034)&     (0.047)&    (12.466)&     (0.058)&     (0.047)&    (33.619)&     (0.037)\\
[1em]
Control Mean        &        0.37&        0.46&      123.26&        0.30&        0.78&      361.21&        0.11\\
Observations        &         844&         844&         332&         332&         332&         332&         332\\
\addlinespace[1mm] \\           & \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textit{D: Endline 4 (10 years)}} \\
[1em]
Treatment           &       0.015&       0.022&      25.167&      -0.138&       0.033&      51.238&      -0.029\\
                    &     (0.032)&     (0.046)&    (12.743)&     (0.059)&     (0.053)&    (31.215)&     (0.042)\\
[1em]
Control Mean        &        0.34&        0.44&      123.78&        0.35&        0.79&      361.95&        0.13\\
Observations        &         861&         861&         308&         309&         309&         309&         309\\
\hline \hline \\                 \end{tabular} \\                 } 

\end{document}
```

The correct table is attached for reference. [image]

Answer (score 1):

- your code did not compile because the `array` and `multirow` packages were missing. However you don't actually need multirows in your headline anyway, so you could remove those instead of adding the package.
- if you want the `A: Endline 1 (18 months)` etc. lines to be on the left, use an `l` column and not a centred `c` column

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

{\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}      \begin{tabular}{l*{7}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}@{}} \toprule       \addlinespace[3mm]        & Migration & No. of migrants & Duration & Migrates to Kolkata & Migrates to urban area & Earnings of migrant worker, typical month & Working in business \\ 
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}\\
\hline \\       \multicolumn{8}{l}{\textit{A: Endline 1 (18 months)}} \\       \addlinespace[1mm] \\
Treatment           &      -0.015&       0.002&      11.767&      -0.004&       0.002&      26.326&       0.042\\
                    &     (0.034)&     (0.041)&     (6.798)&     (0.066)&     (0.055)&    (19.011)&     (0.046)\\
[1em]
Control Mean        &        0.35&        0.39&       37.08&        0.36&        0.83&      139.89&        0.10\\
Observations        &         814&         814&         285&         285&         285&         285&         285\\
\addlinespace[1mm] \\   \multicolumn{8}{l}{\textit{B: Endline 2 (3 years)}} \\
[1em]
Treatment           &       0.029&       0.032&      14.776&      -0.095&      -0.039&      30.574&       0.032\\
                    &     (0.032)&     (0.041)&    (15.332)&     (0.069)&     (0.059)&    (29.920)&     (0.042)\\
[1em]
Control Mean        &        0.29&        0.33&      125.09&        0.38&        0.83&      231.18&        0.15\\
Observations        &         840&         840&         256&         256&         256&         256&         256\\
\addlinespace[1mm] \\  \multicolumn{8}{l}{\textit{C: Endline 3 (7 years)}} \\
[1em]
Treatment           &       0.045&       0.045&     -11.078&       0.067&       0.012&      89.788&       0.017\\
                    &     (0.034)&     (0.047)&    (12.466)&     (0.058)&     (0.047)&    (33.619)&     (0.037)\\
[1em]
Control Mean        &        0.37&        0.46&      123.26&        0.30&        0.78&      361.21&        0.11\\
Observations        &         844&         844&         332&         332&         332&         332&         332\\
\addlinespace[1mm] \\    \multicolumn{8}{l}{\textit{D: Endline 4 (10 years)}} \\
[1em]
Treatment           &       0.015&       0.022&      25.167&      -0.138&       0.033&      51.238&      -0.029\\
                    &     (0.032)&     (0.046)&    (12.743)&     (0.059)&     (0.053)&    (31.215)&     (0.042)\\
[1em]
Control Mean        &        0.34&        0.44&      123.78&        0.35&        0.79&      361.95&        0.13\\
Observations        &         861&         861&         308&         309&         309&         309&         309\\
\hline \hline \\                 \end{tabular} \\                 } 

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same on overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/tnttnbnhgmhc